# How to use HA Proxy server as Load Balancer

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I am trying to use HA Proxy server as a load-balancer between my two web servers. 
The Individual servers are up and running on the specified ports.
But I am not able to hit the web servers through HA Proxy server.
I have configured HA proxy using standard settings as below

/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local0

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# main frontend which proxys to the backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
frontend  main *:80
    mode http
    default_backend             app

backend app
    balance     roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost
    server  app1 10.368.240.116:9091
    server  app2 10.368.240.317:9092
    #server  app3 127.0.0.1:5003 check
    #server  app4 127.0.0.1:5004 check
```

I can successfully curl the above servers from my HA Proxy host machine

```
curl -i "10.368.240.116:9091"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

curl -i "10.368.240.317:9091"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

My HA Proxy server is listening on 80 port
But when I hit it it is giving 503 error as below

```
curl -iv  "127.0.0.1"
* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 80 (#0)
* Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
< Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
< Connection: close
Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html
Content-Type: text/html

<
<html><body><h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
No server is available to handle this request.
</body></html>
* Closing connection 0
```

Can anyone guide where am I doing wrong

Comment: Start by finding the log entries for these failed requests in the HAProxy log.

Comment: Thanks, But I figured out that there wasn't any problem with the configuration. There was some firewall issue. It is resolved now